# WHY I got seg fault here? need help. Want to put integer into char pointer array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 1;
    char* test[8];
    sprintf(test[0],"%d",num);
    printf("%s\n",test[0]);

}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for the pointers in `test`, and `sprintf` tries to write to memory you don't have access to.

Comment: @birryree, that should be an answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did allocate space but you you are passing the wrong thing. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 1;
    char test[8];
    sprintf(test,"%d",num);
    printf("%s\n",test);

}
```

Comment: No.  Now, you're passing a `char **` where there should be a `char *`.

Answer (score 9):

`char *test[8]` is an array of 8 `char *`, or pointers to strings, and since you don't specify, they're all set to garbage values. So `sprintf` is trying to write data to who-knows-where.

You should use `char test[8]` instead, which allocates an array of 8 `char`, and then `sprintf(test, "%d", num);`.

UPDATE: If you want to use `char *` pointers, you should allocate space:

```
char *test = malloc(8 /* see note below */);
sprintf(test, "%d", num);
```

If you want to use an array of `char *` pointers, it works the same:

```
char *test[8]; // 8 pointers to strings
test[0] = malloc(8); // allocate memory for the first pointer
sprintf(test[0], "%d", num);
```

Keep in mind you would have to call `malloc` for each of `test[0]` through `test[7]` individually.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if your compiler supports it you should use `snprintf()`. It's like `sprintf` but it takes an extra parameter which is the size of the buffer:

```
snprintf(test, 8, "%d", num);
```

and guarantees not to use more space than you allow it. It's safer, and if you need to, `snprintf` returns the amount of space it actually wanted, so if you gave it too little room you can `realloc` and try again.

Note: some will say this should be `malloc(8 * sizeof(char))` (or `sizeof *test`). They are wrong (in my objectively-correct opinion; note the sarcasm)! `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so this multiplication is unnecessary.

Some advocate the usage of `TYPE *p = malloc(x * sizeof *p)` so that if TYPE changes, you'll only need to change it in one place, and `sizeof *p` will adapt. I am one of these people, but in my opinion you will rarely need to upgrade a `char *` to another type. Since so many functions use `char *` and would need to be changed in such an upgrade, I'm not worried about making `malloc` lines more flexible.

Comment: +1 for seeing the more likely misunderstanding the OP is having.

Comment: No, I just want to use pointer to strings... I want test[1] is "1" test[2] is 2,, test[10] is "10", like this....

Comment: And you should use snprintf(test, 8, "%d", num) to prevent a buffer overflow.

Comment: @Brian L - True, although `snprintf` is unfortunately a C99 function and not all compilers may have it (though they should). @Andy - Updating answer.

Comment: @Andy: unless you're absolutely sure you want pointers, do `char test[8][12]`, where I've carefully picked "12" to be big enough to hold the decimal string representation of any signed 32-bit value. If `int` is any bigger than 32 bit on your system (which is unlikely but legal), then I've made a bad choice.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - I'm sure with `sizeof(int)`, `CHAR_BIT` and some math (or maybe a little bit-twiddling) you can produce a portable a guaranteed-to-be-big-enough number, though maybe C89 won't let you put it in your arrays.

Comment: @Chris: you can, and it will.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf()` does not allocate space for the string; you must do that yourself beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your warnings:

> `test.c: In function ‘main’:`
>   `test.c:8: warning: ‘test[0]’ is used uninitialized in this function`

You allocate an array of 8 pointers, but use one without initializing it. You must call `malloc` and store the result in `test[0]` before you can write to the memory pointed to by `test[0]`. You `free` it at the end.

A useful function, present in GNU and BSD, is `asprintf`, which will call `malloc` for you to allocate enough memory for the formatted string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num = 1;
    char* test[8];
    asprintf(&test[0],"%d",num);
    printf("%s\n",test[0]);
    free(test[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that you pass the *address* of your pointer to `asprintf` — since your pointer is `test[0]`, its address is `&test[0]`.)

Comment: `asprintf` is useful, but it's important to note that it's a non-standard extension.

Comment: @Andy, as jleedev noted, it is available on BSDs, including [FreeBSD](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/freebsd/man3/asprintf.3.html).  You may want to note your OS(es) in future questions.

Answer (score -3):

```
int main()
{
       char *str[5];
       sprintf(str[0], "%d",55);
       printf("%s\n",str[0]);
       return 0;
}
```

This will be work. But, if you specify variable instead of integer constant value show the segmentation fault will be occur. This error will be happened at the time of sprintf function execution. Because user space memory access.

Comment: Who will allocate memory for str[0] as it is a pointer? This might not work, please check.

Comment: This will not work.  You're assigning to an uninitialized address.

Comment: gcc warns about this (twice) and it segfaults as expected, for me. Obviously wrong.